# How to address a variable in a JQuery Sortable element using JQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, selector

I need to be able to explicitly search for individual Sortable elements using an ID I've created from a global JavaScript variable like this

```
 var theId = presentationId;
  $li.attr("id", theId);

 var $li = $('<li id="'+presentationId+'">
```

Looking at the console in Chrome the element appears as:

```
   firstChild: li#1
```

At the moment I'm addressing individual elements by a description string they contain, like this.

```
   $('ul $li:contains("Introduction")').length)
```

**I can't find a relevant JQuery selector to address the 'id' element and it's value** in this list:

[JQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

I imagine it would be something like:

```
 $("#id=1")
```

Comment: It would be `$("#1")`, but using plain numbers as `id` attributes is only supported from HTML5 onwards. I would suggest you add a string prefix of some kind.

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: I can't get a statement that will recognise the id.

Comment: $("#1") or $("[id='1']") should work. Prefer the 1st one.

Comment: can't get this to work $('ul $li:contains("[id='1']").length )